# Writing an interface as an extension of a generic

Tags: typescript

For example, I have the following interface

```
export interface IUserCredentials {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

I know that I'll be storing this and many other data types inside of a database where they'll be assigned an `id`, a `dateCreated` and a `dateModified`

Rather than write an interface for every single `IDBRecord`, I want to write it all at once, something like:

```
interface DBRecord<Data> extends Data {
  id: number;
  dateCreated: Date
  dateModified: Date
}
```

Of course, this isn't possible, as I cannot reference the generic type outside of the interface's definition.

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a type instead (here, as an intersection type):

```
type DBRecord<T> = T & {
  id: number;
  dateCreated: Date
  dateModified: Date
}

export interface IUserCredentials {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

function foo(entity: DBRecord<IUserCredentials>) {
    ...
}
```

Demo: [typescript playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20DBRecord%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20dateCreated%3A%20Date%0D%0A%20%20dateModified%3A%20Date%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IUserCredentials%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20email%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20password%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(entity%3A%20DBRecord%3CIUserCredentials%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20entity.%0D%0A%7D)

For reference, see [advanced types in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).